# Unable to edit hair created with curve path and circle

Tags: edit-mode, hair, path

I created hair using the above method and all is fine whilst working. Once the model/object is saved/exported and I want to go back to edit any part of the hair I created I'm unable to do so as per attached.
Now, as I mentioned in a previous post I'm new to Blender and it must be the most frustrating piece of software I've come across, yet I'm determined to press on. So please be nice.
Any help greatly appreciated

Blender 3.51

Thank you in advance
GB
[image]

Comment: "Once the model/object is saved/exported" - saving and exporting is usually not the same thing. Saving means to save your scene as a Blender file. Exporting means you probably exported it in a different format like FBX to use it in another software. In this case your (procedural) curves will be converted into a mesh, because FBX cannot use the curve/circle information. If you then re-import it, your curves are gone.

Comment: Hi Gordon and thanks for the reply.. OK so I'll have to save as .blend and then I can edit..

Comment: That's what you usually do in all kinds of software. Save a project in the program's specific file format to make sure you keep all functionalities of the original software available until you need to convert it for use in a different software. Or at least keep a copy in the original format. To say it in plain language: if I want to edit an image later, I cannot print it on paper and expect it will still be editable in my computer afterwards.

Comment: Absolutely.. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.